# Input event app issues

Tags: java, android

I'm working through an input event app. The app has a textfield and a button. The information entered is sent to a receiver app where it handles the action and we must then be able to write to the textview in the Main Activity. Hopefully that explanation is not too confusing.

This is where I built the main app from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

This is where I built the receiver from:
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

The main app loads but the layout is blank. The receiver crashes on load. I can't figure out exactly why, so some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

MainActivity.java (main app)

```
package com.miller.main;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, Bundle savedValues) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Capture our button from layout
        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
        OnClickListener mCorkyListener = null;
        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
        button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);

     // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
        @SuppressWarnings("unused") OnClickListener mCorkyListener1 = new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("null")
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // do something when the button is clicked
                // Capture our button from layout
                button.setOnClickListener(this);
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                Intent intent = null;
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.w("Monday", "Paused");
        super.onPause();
        Log.w("Monday", "Paused");
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.w("Tuesday", "Stopped");
        super.onStop();
        Log.w("Tuesday", "Stopped");
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (main app)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.miller.main.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/text_field"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/corky"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_field" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java (receiver app)

```
package com.miller.receiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
 // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType(); {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUris != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml for the receiver app is just the default at the moment.

Logcat for Receiver app

```
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): Process: com.miller.receiver, PID: 1114
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.miller.receiver/com.miller.receiver.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.miller.receiver.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-09 15:41:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("null")-> can you remove this supress statement. The error is due to a null value being hit on a variable. If you remove the supresswarning you should be able to see which variable is initialised with null value. either assign a value for that variable or do a try/catch  to stop your app from crashing.

Comment: If I try to do that above the flag line for example, it gives me this warning: Null pointer access: The variable intent can only be null at this location

Comment: i got the culprit---Intent intent = null;
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);   you are trying to use the intent in your list which is essentially null as per the previous line. you need to intialize the intent with some meaningful content and the use it in the list.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but what would I initialize it to? It's not really making sense to me, what this variable would be doing.

Comment: can you enlighten me on what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: you can do so many things with intent and is explained in this link "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html"

Comment: change to          List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0); if you are simply trying to retrieve the list of activities that can be performed on a intent, you should be calling the sendInent instead of creating a new and null intent. did u add this null intent intentionally or did you add this to fix some errore?

Comment: So like I said, I have an app that has a text field and a button. I'm going to write something in the text field, and when I press the button, the text will be sent and I will be prompted with a fragment to select which app should handle the action. If I choose the receiver, the data I send will be written to the TextView (of the receiver).

Comment: got it. the code is getting the list of activities that can be performed and for that you have added a new object named intent . replace all "intent" to "sendIntent" and it should work. remove the null value intent initialization

Comment: Still doesn't work, weird.